# SQLite and Julia how to avoid the NOT NULL constraint?

Tags: sqlite, error-handling, julia, notnull

I am dealing with CSV-Files and try to import them into a SQLite Database via Julia (SQLite-Package)
From my knowlege SQLite by default accepts "NULL" for all columns in a table. However since I am having some columns containing some entries with "NA" or are empty (=NULL) CSV Files with those arguments can not be loaded into the Database and result in:
ERROR: SQLiteException("NOT NULL constraint failed: FinalComputation.CneName on statement

Unfortunately the Documentation of SQLite.jl includes no Information about handling that constraint in the load-statement.

Load Statement:

```
tbl = CSV.File(files) |> SQLite.load!(db, "FinalComputation")
```

Does anyone experience the same errors or has any idea how to solve this issue?

Thank you very much!

Edit: It seems like a very specifiy problem... if I first load the CSV-File with the "NULL" entry into the database the following ones without that issue do not result in any error messages. However if i first load a CSV-File without "NULL"s the error occurs... i don't know...

Comment: Maybe the first table you load establishes the schema and the following tables must follow the same schema? A work-around would be to temporarily store these tables in a `DataFrame`, which would properly identify the right schema, and then store such a table in SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the desire to auto-detect the schema of a file even before reading it, in order to prepare a DB to accept the data. This is impossible but `CSV.jl` attempts this by reading the first `rows_to_check` (30 by default) lines of a file and doing some clever guessing.

SQLite indeed allows NULLs by default, but `SQLite.jl` translates types which cannot be `missing` into fields with `NON NULL` constraints.

When the file being read has all the missing values needed in the first lines, the auto-detection works and no error produced. But this is clearly an unstable way to handle this.

Here is a way to force all the fields in the autodetected file to accept `missing` values:

```
using CSV
using SQLite
using Tables

# get CSV.jl initial guess of types using first 30 rows
f = CSV.File(first(files); limit=30)
schema_guess = Tables.schema(f)

# force all column types to be Union with Missing
types_with_missing = 
  [Missing <: T ? T : Union{Missing, T} for T in schema_guess.types]

# now reading files with the fixed types
tbl = CSV.File(files; types=types_with_missing) |> 
  SQLite.load!(db, "FinalComputation")
```

This should probably be refactored into a function in your code. If the types of the columns are known, it is best to skip this guess phase and input the types in the `types=` parameter.